# SQLite FTS in my app

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, android-sqlite

I am trying to implement FTS for my app. I have SQLite DB that is about 120MB. Two **text** columns on which I would like to do search against user entered words. 
I have questions regarding VRT.

1. Will be data be redundant when I create VRT for those two **text** columns?
2. Is this VRT created only once or it is to be created every time app re-starts?
3. What will be best way to search the `text` columns if I have to search for EVERY word entered by user in search bar. Like "This is a sentence". I would like to search for each of "This", "is","a", "sentence". You get the idea. I may ignore "is", "a" in real scenario.

   4. Is it possible with FTS to search on Non-English text like Arabic?

I tried to search on google and SO. But I didn't find anything satisfactory.
This is my first app and have been working on it for many days. So far it has been learning experience.

Comment: This is documented in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html).